# switching char cases, pointer problems

Tags: c, pointers

The goal of my program is to switch the cases of the two letters inputted. For example a turns to A and B turns to b. I am having trouble getting my code to work when I know my logic is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>;

void switcharoo(char *ch1,char *ch2)
{

    if(*ch1 >= 'a' && *ch1 <= 'z' && *ch2 >= 'A' && *ch2 <= 'Z')
    {
        *ch1 = 'A' + *ch1 - 'a';
        *ch2 = 'a' + *ch2 - 'A';
    }
    else if(*ch1 >= 'A' && *ch1 <= 'Z' && *ch2 >= 'A' && *ch2 <= 'Z')
    {
        *ch1 = 'a' + *ch1 - 'A';
        *ch2 = 'a' + *ch2 - 'A';
    }
    else if(*ch1 >= 'a' && *ch1 <= 'z' && *ch2 >= 'a' && *ch2 <= 'z')
    {
        *ch1 = 'A' + *ch1 - 'a';
        *ch2 = 'A' + *ch2 - 'a';
    }
    else if(*ch1 >= 'A' && *ch1 <= 'Z' && *ch2 >= 'a' && *ch2 <= 'z')
    {
        *ch1 = 'a' + *ch1 - 'A';
        *ch2 = 'A' + *ch2 - 'a';
    }
}

int main()
{
    char lettera,letterb;

    printf("Please input a first character: ");
    scanf("%c", &lettera);
    printf("Please input a first character: ");
    scanf("%c", &letterb);

    switcharoo(lettera,letterb);
    printf("%c\n %c\n",lettera,letterb);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait, why does `switcharoo` need to deal with two characters at once? Simplify.

Comment: because my assignment says so ;[

Comment: @JonathonReinhart , any question which makes no sense , always turns out to be an assignment :)

Comment: @BarathBushan No kidding man. I understand giving assignments that force the students to learn things like functions, by-ref parameters, etc. But how about something that is useful and follows some pattern that would be used in the real world? Jeez.

Comment: Make a function that handles a single char, and call it twice? Or is that too far outside the box..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%c", &lettera);
scanf("%c", &letterb);
```

This probably isn't doing what you want.  The newline (enter) character you presumably type after entering the first letter (given your prompts imply you're expecting them on different lines) will be read in as the second letter.  You'd have to type two letters then a newline for them to be read into your `lettera` and `letterb` successfully... can just prompt once for 2 characters.  Also, it's good practice to check the return value of `scanf` to ensure it got the input you requested....

Comment: @dLiGHT , atleast make you comments look aesthetic , if not your programs :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am required to create my own function, I'd use `#include <ctype.h>` functions to make my life easier.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char lettera,letterb;

    printf("Please input a first character: ");
    scanf("%c", &lettera);
    printf("Please input a first character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letterb); // note the space in front of %c to flush '\n'

    // lettera conversion
    if(isupper(lettera)) {
        lettera = tolower(lettera);
    } else if (islower(lettera)) {
        lettera = toupper(lettera);
    }

    // letterb conversion
    if(isupper(letterb)) {
        letterb = tolower(letterb);
    } else if (islower(letterb)) {
        letterb = toupper(letterb);
    }

    printf("%c\n %c\n",lettera,letterb);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
switcharoo(lettera,letterb);
```

as

```
switcharoo(&lettera,&letterb); //passing address of lettera and letterb
```

as you are taking `char *` in the function.

Comment: I tried this, and then my code goes on to never call the function, and proceeds to enter the same letter twice.

Comment: That would be problem with `scanf` for chars, try to read chars using `getc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not run. The compiler will give error as con not convert char to char *.

Try calling your function the way Rohan has suggested.

Or you can simplify your function. Use it for one parameter only and call it twice.

```
char changeCase(char ch) {
  if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    ch -= 32;
  if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    ch += 32;
  return ch;
}
```

In main you can write,

```
char lettera, letterb;
//get values of lettera and letterb
lettera = changeCase(lettera);
letterb = changeCase(letterb);
```